# What is/means/does `Magento\Framework\Model\OrchestratorPool`?

Tags: magento2, di

I found in `di.xml` from the [catalog module this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml#L541):

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Model\OrchestratorPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="operations" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="read" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Model\Operation\Read</item>
                <item name="create" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Model\Operation\Write\Create</item>
                <item name="update" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Model\Operation\Write\Update</item>
                <item name="delete" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Model\Operation\Write\Delete</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

What does it do? what does it mean? Where is this used and what for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This class is a part of new database persistence framework. It will allow to save data interfaces implemented in arbitrary way and provide more flexibility, as you will no longer be required to make your model extend `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel`.

At the moment framework under development but parts of it were introduced for one of the features we are working on. We do not recommend start using it yet as it will significantly change. But it might be interesting to take a look.

The main class is `Magento\Framework\Model\EntityManager`. EntityManager uses `Magento\Framework\Model\OrchestratorPool` to get operation for the entity, for instance `Magento\Framework\Model\Operation\Write\Create`. Operation uses different actions to perform its function. Some actions can be configured to use handlers, for instance `Magento\Framework\Model\Entity\Action\CreateRelation`.

Also, see di configuration for `Magento\Framework\Model\OrchestratorPool`, `Magento\Framework\Model\Entity\MetadataPool` and `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Relation\ActionPool`.

You may find examples of using framework in `Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I admit it does not make sense 100% to me yet, but it should be enough to get me started. Thanks. One small side question. Since `OrchestratorPool` is general and not only catalog specific, shouldn't the declaration in my question be added in a different `di.xml`, not the one in the catalog module?

Comment: Yes, it should not be in catalog. It will be moved to different module

Comment: Note to self and all: Within M2.1 this has been moved to `app/etc/di.xml` and the names of the classes are a bit different: `OrchestratorPool` is now called `OperationPool`.