# Magento 2.1 EntityManager getList without Collection

Tags: magento-2.1, entity-manager

From my understanding, the classic Magento Models will be deprecated in favor of the new EntityManager.

Loading and Saving Simple Objects is no problem so far, but currently, I'm stuck with loading Lists of DB entities.

So my question is: How can I load a List of Entities without utilizing the Collection Resource Model?

As far as I have come it seems that this is simply not implemented yet, since there are no db operations for such task https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/EntityManager/Db

Comment: Check here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98190/what-is-means-does-magento-framework-model-orchestratorpool